# Math real numbers analysis.

Tags: real-analysis

Given a real number $x$, and a natural number $N\gt 1$. Consider the numbers :

$0, x−\lfloor x\rfloor,2x−\lfloor2x\rfloor,\ldots,Nx−\lfloor Nx\rfloor.$

Show that some pair of these numbers differs by at most $\frac 1N$.

Conclude that there exist integers $h$, $k$ such that, $|kx−h| < \frac 1N$, and $0 < k \leq N$.

PS: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ means floor of x.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Divide the interval $[0,1)$ to $N$ subintervals $[0,1/N)$, $[1/N,2/N)$,$\ldots$,
$[(N-1)/N,1)$. There are $N+1$ numbers in your list, so some two of them will fall into the same subinterval by the pigeonhole principle. Can you take it from there?

Comment: no sorry I can't, I kind of didn't understand the question that I posted :( I am confused..

Comment: Rebecca came up with the same idea, and she fleshed it out. The pigeon hole principle tells you that there has to be two integers $k_1,k_2$, $0\le k_1<k_2\le N$ such that the fractional parts of $k_1x$ and $k_2x$ are within $1/N$ of each other. Then it follows that $(k_2-k_1)x$ is within $1/N$ of an integer $h$.

Answer (score 2):

A more general result holds: if we take any $N+1$ real numbers in $[0,1]$ then the minimum difference between any two is at most $1/N$.

*Proof*: Sort the list of real numbers $$(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{N+1})$$ in ascending order and take the differences $$d_i=a_{i+1}-a_i$$ for $1 \leq i \leq N$.  We know $$d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_N \leq 1$$ (since $a_{N+1}=a_1+d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_N$).  Hence $$N \min_{i \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}} d_i \leq d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_N \leq 1$$ and the result follows.

(In the stated problem, we should ensure that $kx-\lfloor kx \rfloor \in [0,1]$ for all $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,N\}$, regardless of the value of $x \in \mathbb{R}$.)

---

For the second part:  If $$(ax-\lfloor ax \rfloor) - (bx-\lfloor bx \rfloor) \leq \frac{1}{N}$$ then $$(\underbrace{a-b}_k)x-(\underbrace{\lfloor ax \rfloor-\lfloor bx \rfloor}_h) \leq \frac{1}{N}$$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\lceil A \rceil \ge A \ge \lfloor A \rfloor$

$\lceil A \rceil - \lfloor A \rfloor = 0 \text{ or }1$

Another hint: Divide both sides by $N$.

$Nx - \lfloor Nx \rfloor \le c$

$\dfrac{Nx}{N} - \dfrac {\lfloor Nx \rfloor}{N} \le \dfrac{c}{N}$

Comment: how can this help me?

Comment: You use these facts to prove that $Nx−\lfloor Nx \rfloor$ is always in the range $[0,1]$. Then you can show that the absolute difference between any two points in this interval will also lie inside of the interval.